# Beanstalk instance NTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Our stand alone instance before was needed to be configured with it's NTP so it can go through google's API.

Now we are using beanstalk, is it possible to configure it through some ebextensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk instances come already configured with NTP.

“Instances in your Elastic Beanstalk environment use Network Time Protocol (NTP) to syncronize the system clock. If instances are unable to communicate on UDP port 123, the clock may go out of sync, causing issues with Elastic Beanstalk health reporting. Ensure that your VPC security groups and network ACLs allow inbound and outbound UDP traffic on port 123 to avoid these issues."

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc.html